# Use Generator to input datasets but get IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
model.fit(x,y, epochs=10000, batch_size=1)
```

The above codes works fine. When I use a function to feed the data in the model, something went wrong.

```
model.fit(GData(), epochs=10000, batch_size=1)
```

> per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

The GData() function is given below:

```
def GData():
  return (x,y)
```

x is a numpy array with dimension (2, 63,    85)
y is a numpy array with dimension (2, 63, 41000)

This is the whole codes:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def MSE( y_true, y_pred):
    error = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y_true-y_pred))
    return error

data = np.load("Data.npz")
x = data['x'] # (2,63,   85)
y = data['y'] # (2,63,41000)

frame = x.shape[1]
InSize = x.shape[2]
OutSize = y.shape[2]

def GData():
    return (x,y)


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(1000, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(frame,InSize)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(OutSize))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=MSE)#'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(GData(), epochs=10000, batch_size=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function `GData` is not actually a generator as it is returning a value rather than yielding a value. Regardless, we should take a look at the `fit()` method and its documentation which you can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).
From this, we see that the first two arguments to `fit()` are x and y. Going further, we see that x is limited to a few types. Namely, generators, numpy arrays, tf.data.Datasets, and a few others. An important thing to note in the documentation is that if x is a generator, it must be `A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets)`. I am assuming this is what you are looking for. If this is the case, you will need to modify your `GData` function so that it is actually a generator. This can be done as such

```
batch_size = 1
EPOCHS = 10000
def GData():
    for _ in range(EPOCHS): # Iterate through epochs. Note that this can be changed to be while True so that the generator yields indefinitely. The model will stop training after the amount of epochs you specify in the fit method.
        for i in range(0, len(x), batch_size): # Iterate through batches
            yield (x[i:batch_size], y[i:batch_size]) # Yield batches for training
```

Then, you have to specify the amount of steps per epoch in your `fit()` call so your model knows when to stop at each epoch.

```
model.fit(GData(), epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=x.shape[0]//batch_size)
```